# How to conduct large-scale lookups in SQL?

Tags: sql, lookup, lookup-tables

I have a SQL table with several million rows, each row contains columns ID1 and ID2.

I'm trying to lookup the entries in this table for 100,000 unique combinations of ID1 and ID2 and export the results of this query to a CSV file.

In the past for smaller numbers of rows I've been able to use a query along the lines of

```
SELECT * 
FROM Database.Table 
WHERE ID1 = 5 AND ID2 = 3 
   OR ID1 = 9 AND ID2 = 33 
   OR ID1 = 59 AND ID2 = 332...
```

However this seems to break once I get beyond a few thousand combinations of ID1 and ID2.

What is the best approach for handling large lookups like this in SQL?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and performance tuning is quite vendor specific Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1):

Load the CSV file into a table with two columns:  `id1` and `id2`.  Make these the primary key.

Then use `join` or `exists`:

```
select bt.*
from bigtable bt join
     csvtable csv
     on bt.id1 = csv.id1 and bt.id2 = csv.id2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried IN statement? https://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-in.aspx/

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE (ID1, ID2) in ( (5, 3), (10, 6), ..)`